# If every page frame has a copy in the disk?

Tags: linux, memory, operating-system, virtual-memory

if every page frame has a copy in the secondary storage, and when is the time to make this copy and record the mapping.

What would happen when MMU meets an empty page entry. If there are free physical pages at the time, why bother to make a copy at some points(before or now).

why can't just ignore it and create this copy only when the page frame is needed to be swapped out? wouldn't it be too costly(and not lazy) to reserve copies for every page frames, especially nowadays with more and more physical memory?

One website said that virtual pages are initially all on disk
https://computationstructures.org/lectures/vm/vm.html#7

Comment: FWIW, on Windows the pagefile is dynamically sized by default: https://serverfault.com/questions/27568/what-exactly-does-system-managed-size-mean-for-a-windows-pagefile

Comment: @Dai edit my question. If what the link said is true, when will the mapping of virtual pages and the disk is created/initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no other related QA in SO fully clear my confusion. I found the answer after read an online ebook "Understanding the Linux® Virtual Memory Manager".

Figure in the book for handling page fault.

[image]

The answer is.

> if every page frame has a copy in the secondary storage, and when is
> the time to make this copy and record the mapping?

No, the kernel swap out page frames only when there are no free pages left, and this could happen whenever an `alloc_page` is called(May happen at the first time accessing an empty PTE, or access an PTE with page already been swapped out).

In function `alloc_page`, nonfree page frame may be swapped out to make a space for this requirement call.

> What would happen when MMU meets an empty page entry. If there are
> free physical pages at the time, why bother to make a copy at some
> points(before or now).

`do_no_page` would be called in which `alloc_page` would be called for most cases.